# Can I extract this XHR data with Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to extract data from this [link](https://www.pexels.com/leaderboard/all-time.js?format=js&seed=&page=1&type=) with Scrapy. I am looking to loop through these urls with page=1 through like the top 100 pages and extract every instance of  `<a href=\"/@eberhardgross\">\n` for example. Ultimately just trying to grab the username there but there are other `<a href="">` on the page but if I could extract just the username that would be great but if I have to get all `<a href="">` that's fine I can sort them and get just the @. Just wondering if I can do this via scrapy?

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"

def start_requests(self):
    url = "https://www.pexels.com/leaderboard/all-time.js?format=js&seed=&page=%(page_number)s&type="
    page_to_crawl = 100
    for page_number in range(page_to_crawl):
        yield scrapy.Request(url %{'page_number': page_number}, self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
    usernames = response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "@")]/@href').getall()
```

Answer (score 0):

To crawl several pages you can use `start_requests` to iterate on pages:

```py
def start_requests(self):
    url = "https://www.pexels.com/leaderboard/all-time.js?format=js&seed=&page=%(page_number)s&type="
    page_to_crawl = 100
    for page_number in range(page_to_crawl):
        yield scrapy.Request(url %{'page_number': page_number}, self.parse)
```

And in your `parse` method you can get HREFs that contains **@** in it by xpath:

```py
def parse(self, response):
    usernames = response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "@")]/@href').getall()
    yield {
         'usernames': usernames
    }
```

Comment: I have updated my original request with what I am trying to use for the scrapy crawl. Ignore the class name as I am using the sample python examples so I am calling the crawl and storing in a json file but nothing is in the json file?

Comment: @johncsmith427 `yield` the result to get JSON output file. I've updated the answer.